# How to reverse a hashmap of list in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a hashmap with an object key and an arraylist of another object as values:

```
HashMap<Object1, ArrayList<Object2>> map;
```

An Object2 can belong to multiple Object1. I want to reverse it so that it becomes:

```
HashMap<Object2, ArrayList<Object1>> reversed;
```

How can I do that?

I have seen solutions to hashmaps with an object key and an object value, but differently, my problem revolves around an arraylist as the value.

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate.  Google's Guava library has something called a `BiMap`, which is a bidirectional map.  There is a method `BiMap.inverse()` which will do just what you need.

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this:

```
HashMap<Object2, ArrayList<Object1>> reversed = new HashMap<>();

for(Map.Entry<Object1, ArrayList<Object2>> entry : map.entrySet()){
    List<Object2> list = entry.getValue();
    for(Object2 obj : list){
        if(reversed.containsKey(obj)){
            reversed.get(obj).add(entry.getKey());
        }else{
            reversed.put(obj, new ArrayList<Object1>(Arrays.asList(new Object1[]{entry.getKey()})));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping if there is another quicker way. But if there is not, then this would work.

Comment: The inner loop’s body can be shortened to `reversed.computeIfAbsent(obj, k -> new ArrayList<Object1>()).add(entry.getKey());`.

Answer (score 5):

Using streams:

```
Map<Object2, Set<Object1>> reversed = map.entrySet().stream()
            .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(o2 -> Pair.of(o2, e.getKey())))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getKey, HashMap::new, Collectors.mapping(Pair::getValue, Collectors.toSet())));
```

Explanations:

1. Since there are multiple values, it create a tuple for each value attached to a given Object1:

   > e -> e.getValue().stream().map(o2 -> Pair.of(o2, e.getKey()))
2. flatMap(...) allows for transforming one entry to 0 or more items on the resulting stream
3. Mapping the values Object1 to a set

   > Collectors.mapping(Pair::getValue, Collectors.toSet())
4. Final container creation:

   > HashMap::new
5. Grouping by Object2 in pair.getKey() which feeds the groups to the mapping described in (3):

   > Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getKey, HashMap::new, Collectors.mapping(...))

Comment: This showed me the little tidbit I was missing. Great answer!